# How to read whenever there is an incoming message in Tcp socket programming in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-4.5, tcpclient

I have a server-client program written in .NET C#. I have used socket programming and so far both the server and client are working. There is only one server instance, while I am able connect multiple clients all together. 
Right now my code works like the following scenario.
[image]

When I start the Server code, it starts **Listening**. When I start a client, it waits for a command to be written on the console. After I write something, the client sends that to the server, then the server does something with that, writes something back. This is how the cycle goes. Like a ping-pong game.
My client code is availabe in this [link](http://pastebin.com/TBf2Wiee).

**Problem and what I want:**
With this functionality, my client cannot listen to the server unless it writes something to the server. I want to make it listen whenever there is an incoming message. My server code is fine and the sequence for server(listen then write) is okay. The client sequence(write the listen) is okay as well, but my client cannot read unless it writes. Suppose two clients are communicating with the server. client1 tells the server- "hey I need something that belongs to client2", then server will send a message to client2. With the current code, client2 cannot listen to the message because its actually waiting to write. Hope I made myself clear.

How can I achieve that? Any code samples will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Just call BeginReceive().  Your callback runs whenever the server sends something unsolicited.  Call BeginReceive() again after you processed the data and sent a response.

Comment: @HansPassant I was actually worried about receiving the entire data from the server. So then I decided to loop over the buffer. But I used BeginReceive() on the server side. I will check again!

Comment: @HansPassant the problem I find with BeginReceive() is that the code just blocks at that part and does not proceed unless it gets any response from the server. This isn't the case with Read() method, it just returns 0 when there's nothing in the buffer. I am still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You will need more than on thread on the client. One for accepting console input & sending and one for reading the TCP stream (blockingly) and displaying. Getting it to look like IRC on the console is a bit tricky because user written characters and received characters will interleave.

Comment: I actually tried some threading, may be I did it in the wrong way or something, didn't work out. Can you show that in a code? Maybe edit my pastebin? Thanks

Comment: @Pro.metal no. Please don't ask someone else to do the work for you. Show your threaded implementation instead and describe what is not working. Or google for the solution: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_u4f1AA5I0M

Comment: You may have got me wrong. Anyways, here's my code http://pastebin.com/yzXrpFcF . My thread understanding is at beginners level and does not go the way I want it to.

Comment: the YouTube link guy didn't complete his project. Why share a link that is incomplete? I have tried [this](http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server) as well. Doesn't help.